# Getting data from Map inside a Map with streams

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have a problem with receiving data from Map nested in another Map.

```
private Map<Customer, Map<Item,Integer>> orders;
```

I'm generating this map from JSON, its add Customer if he is not on the list with Items and their number.
If Customer is already in the map then key Item in the second map is updated and if a key was there already then Integer which is the number of items is updated.
Classes Customer and Items are not connected I mean Class Customer don't have field Items and class Items don't have a field Customer.

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Integer age;
    private BigDecimal money;
}


public class Item {

    private String name;
    private String category;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

Using streams I want to get for example Customer who paid the most for items but I have problem with getting this data from the map, it was not so hard with List but now I can't figure it out.

Ok I did figure out something like this and it seems to be working but I'm sure it can be simplified.

```
Customer key = customersMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> e.getValue()
                                .entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(o -> o.getKey().getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(o.getValue())))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, t -> t.getValue().stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .orElseThrow()
                .getKey();
```

Your answer Naman was very helpful so maybe you can give me advice about this.
This is how I'm receiving it from JSON.

```
JsonConverterCustomer jsonConverterCustomer = new JsonConverterCustomer(FILENAME3);
List<Order> orders = jsonConverterCustomer.fromJson().orElseThrow();
 

Map<Customer, Map<Item, Integer>> customersMap = new HashMap<>();

        

for (Order order : orders) {
            if (!customersMap.containsKey(order.getCustomer())) {
                addNewCustomer(customersMap, order);
            } else {
                for (Product product : order.getItems()) {
                    if (!customersMap.get(order.getCustomer()).containsKey(items)) {
                        addNewCustomerItem(item, customersMap.get(order.getCustomer()));
                    } else {
                        updateCustomerItem(customersMap, order, item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


private static void updateCustomerProduct(Map<Customer, Map<Item, Integer>> customersMap, Order order, Item item) {
        customersMap.get(order.getCustomer())
                .replace(item,
                        customersMap.get(order.getCustomer()).get(item),
                        customersMap.get(order.getCustomer()).get(item) + 1);
    }

    private static void addNewCustomerItem(Item item, Map<Item, Integer> itemIntegerMap) {
        itemIntegerMap.put(item, 1);
    }

    private static void addNewCustomer(Map<Customer, Map<Item, Integer>> customersMap, Order order) {
        Map<Item, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
        addNewCustomerItem(order.getItems().get(0), temp);
        customersMap.put(order.getCustomer(), temp);
    }
```

Order class is a class which one help me receiving data from JSON
It is a simple class with Customer as a field and List as a field.
As you can see I'm receiving List of Orders and from it, I'm creating this Map.
Can I make it more functional? Using streams? I was trying to do but not sure how;/

Comment: Post the code which you have already tried.

Comment: It's not so simple because I tried a couple of times remove it try a different approach and always somewhere in the process there is something I can't overcome.

Comment: I doubt if anyone will help you without you show some effort. The way SO works is, first you try to solve the problem yourself and if you do not succeed, you post your code and the description of the thing where you are stuck.

Comment: I understand that mate but I wasted much time for it didn't figure it out so I'm trying here because I'm out of ideas I'm just stuck I'm almost sure that i should use entrySet and form there try collect some data but every time I'm hitting the wall;/

Comment: I don't even need a pure solution just example how to handle it getting some data from nested maps. Then I will try to figure something out by myself I just don't want to spend another hour on it w/o any results.

Comment: Sometimes streams are not the best way to accomplish something. Sure, they are cool, but remember that one of the most important aspects of software engineering is maintainability. If you develop a super-complex stream solution, but the next developer can't figure out what's going on in order to debug it, you've wasted your time. Try solving the problem without streams first, and see if that gives you any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to make it more maintainable/readable as Jason pointed out and at the same time simplify the logic performed.

- One, you can get rid of one of the stages in the pipeline and merge `map` and `reduce` into a single pipeline.
- Another would be to abstract out per customer computation of the total amount paid by them.

So the abstraction would look like the following and work on the inner maps for your input:

```
private BigDecimal totalPurchaseByCustomer(Map<Item, Integer> customerOrders) {
    return customerOrders.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> o.getKey().getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(o.getValue())))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Now to easily fit this in while you iterate for each customer entry, you can do that in a single `collect` itself:

```
private Customer maxPayingCustomer(Map<Customer, Map<Item, Integer>> customersMap) {
    Map<Customer, BigDecimal> customerPayments = customersMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> totalPurchaseByCustomer(e.getValue())));
    return customerPayments.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

Comment: @Tausa It might be worth a new question and do ensure you try out something by yourself before posting it. :)
From just an overview, you can create the `Map` using collectors toMap, it might though need a `flatMap`ping as an intermediate operation though.